# iOS - Can I disable accessibility on cell.textLabel.text?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I have an app that contains a view with a cell that uses the built-in cell.textLabel and a custom UITextField in cell.contentView.

I am working with Voiceover and accessibility and the desired behavior would be that whenever I tap anywhere in the cell, the accessibility element for the UITextField would be selected.

The behavior that I am actually seeing is that the cell.textLabel accessibility labels are taking over.  When I don't have cell.textLabel set to anything, everything works as expected.  I have also attempted to set the "isAccessibilityElement" property  with no luck:

```
[cell.textLabel.text setIsAccessibilityElement:NO];
```

Does anyone know how to make this work the way I want?

Comment: The text is never an accessibility element to begin with (it's just a string). Did you mean `[cell.textLabel setIsAccessibilityElement:NO];`?

Comment: Do you want to restrict user interaction on your cell.textLabel? correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Sorry - yes , I did mean: `[cell.textLabel setIsAccessibilityElement:NO];`  It still didn't disable the accessibility element for the textLabel

Comment: @Dilip - I'm not so worried about restricting user interation on the cell.textLabel, as the user already can't change anything there.  I'm more concerned about disabling the accessibility element for the label.  I have also tried to explicitly disable user interaction to no avail: `    [cell.textLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure this out using this:
`cell.textLabel.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;`